# How can I reload data in a db table?

Tags: mysql, database

I got following question:
I have a table which i will read with a program, at the meantime this table will be refreshed everyday. But the refresh program is not reliable, it may fail at anytime. I got following solutions:

**1.** The refresh program writes data to a tmp table, after success, i drop the read table, then rename the tmp table to read table.

**2.** I create three tables T1, T2, S. T1 and T2 are the data tables. S is the status table recording the table(T1 or T2) for read. The refresh program first query the S for current read table, then another is the write table, loading data into write table, after success, updating S making the write table to be the read table. Every time, the query program first fetch the read table from S, then read data from it.

I want to know which one is better and WHY? Or ur guys have any better solutions. 
Appreciate for ur help, thanks!

Comment: What language/framework are you using, and can you describe the application you are building?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The read program is base on java, the write program can be scala

Comment: Not a single of those approaches make sense at all. If the program is unreliable and can fail at any time, what does sticking any amount of tables help with?

Comment: @Mjh, if it fails, we can just fetch the old data.

Comment: So you assumed that you will fail fetching from one table and in that case you assumed you will succeed fetching from ANOTHER table? How's that sensible? I don't see what problem you're solving. You have a program that you said is unreliable, and you want to increase that reliability. How is adding more tables achieving that?

Comment: @Mjh I am not increasing the program reliability. I just want to make the data is more available while the refresh program is refreshing the data.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your data model. 
Do you have constraints between tables? If so you'll need to delete/insert in the right order.
Also which database are you using?

In your fisrt solution you drop the table. If you are using triggers or stored procedures or any other kind of database stuff it's gonna be invalid after the drop.
So you'll need to recompile objects.

Also why you need to delete all rows in your table?
You can add a date field, ie dupdated and keep for example a retention of 1 day or 5 days or anyway.
Then you purge your data of previous day when process of load is done and validated.

Comment: I am using mysql. I only have an index on the table. I delete the data cause they are calculated everyday basing on latest original data.

Comment: more specific，I am building a recommend sys. And I need a table to cache      some data. the columns are [userid, geohash, profile_list, cf_list], profile_list  stores list of [restaurantId, score] calculated using user profile algorithm, and the cf_list is calculated using collaborating filter algorithm.